# How can I return a Color from a function

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am trying to use a function to cycle through numbers to determine the color.**

I was going to use a switch statement but I was unsure of how to make it work on dart. I'm quite new to flutter and previously used HTML CSS and JS.

**How can I return the color from the function to be used?**

```
var color;
  customColor() => {
        if (colorCounter == 0)
          {
            color = Colors.green,
            colorCounter++,
          }
        else if (colorCounter == 1)
          {
            color = Colors.amber,
            colorCounter++,
          }
        else if (colorCounter == 2)
          {
            color = Colors.red,
            colorCounter++,
          }
        else if (colorCounter == 3)
          {
            color = Colors.blue,
            colorCounter++,
          }
        else if (colorCounter == 4)
          {
            color = Colors.purple,
            colorCounter = 0,
          },
          return color,
      };
```

I want to use it in the BoxDecoration color part of the following widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: MyAlphabeticalConceptsWidget.orderedConcepts.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    **

 - color: customColor,

**
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(MyAlphabeticalConceptsWidget
                            .orderedConcepts.keys
                            .elementAt(index)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          MyAlphabeticalConceptsWidget.orderedConcepts.values
                              .elementAt(index),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```dart
  Color customColor() {
    if (colorCounter == 0) {
      color = Colors.green;
      colorCounter++;
    } else if (colorCounter == 1) {
      color = Colors.amber;
      colorCounter++;
    } else if (colorCounter == 2) {
      color = Colors.red;
      colorCounter++;
    } else if (colorCounter == 3) {
      color = Colors.blue;
      colorCounter++;
    } else if (colorCounter == 4) {
      color = Colors.purple;
      colorCounter = 0;
    }
    return color;
  }
```

I would like a switch case for in this example

```dart
  Color customColor() {
    switch (colorCounter) {
      case 0:
        colorCounter++;
        return Colors.green;
     .....
      default:
        return Colors.amber; // when no color match
    }
  }
```

And use case

```dart
color: customColor(),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked.
You are truly gods gift to earth.

Comment: So does the Color definition allow for the return function? and this would work with String Int etc.?

Comment: If you like to return String, you change the return type and return string , more about [functions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions)

Comment: @Ankere It will be better if you accept the answer in case of if it worked so that it would be reference in future for others.

Comment: Thank you. I had to wait 10 minutes before i could accept it and then i forgot.